# Hql, How to write join query between tables that has one to many relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have `2` tables. `1st` one have `oneToMany` relationship with `2nd`.

Class Author

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
Public class Author{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AuthorId")
    private int autherId;

    @Column(name = "AuthorName")
    private String authorName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="AuthorId",referencedColumnName="AuthorId")
    List<Book> Books;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Class Book

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
Public class Book{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BookId")
    private int bookId;

    @Column(name = "BookName")
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name = "AuthorId")
    private int authorId;

    //getter and setter
}
```

How can I write a `Hql` query so that I will get all author's and there books , with a condition that book name should starts with `hello`

I know using a query like this,

```
  from Author;
```

I can fetch all author's and there books,but how to give condition on book?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think its something like this:

```
select a from Author as a join a.Book as ab where ab.AuthorId like '%"hello"%';
```

not sure about a.Book though, it could also be a.Books as your columnname is named like that.

Comment: It worked. But instead of `join a.Book` as per my mapping `join a.Books` is to be used.